# How to use an IN clause in iBATIS?

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I'm using [iBATIS](http://ibatis.apache.org/) to create select statements. Now I would like to implement the following SQL statement with iBATIS:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN ('value1', 'value2');
```

With the following approach, the statement is not prepared correctly and no result returns:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN #listOfValues#;
```

iBATIS seems to restructure this list and tries to interpret it as a string.

How can I use the IN clause correctly?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's a blog post that answers your question:

[iBatis: Support for Array or List Parameter with SQL IN Keyword](http://mybatis.github.com/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html)

```
<select id="select-test" resultMap="MyTableResult" parameterClass="list">
select * from my_table where col_1 in
  <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
   #[]#
  </iterate>
</select>
```

> And in Java you should pass in a
>   java.util.List. E.g.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(3);
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
List objs = sqlMapClient.queryForList("select-test",list);
```

Comment: all this xml makes me want to vomit, but thx for the info very helpful for a project where I have to use ibatis

Comment: I can't believe I just upvoted an iBatis question/answer. When will this project be over, and I can stop using iBatis?

Comment: Nah, iBatis is fantastic.  At least you get to write SQL instead of some other abomination.

Comment: Could you please read my similar post, thanks !: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343006/how-to-create-an-sql-in-clause-in-ibatis-2-for-an-sql-update-or-sql-select-state

Answer (score 12):

How about

```
<select id="foo" parameterClass="Quuxly" resultClass="Flobitz">
    select * from table
    <dynamic prepend="where col1 in ">
        <iterate property="list_of_values" open="('" close="')" conjunction=",  ">
            #list_of_values[]#
        </iterate>
    </dynamic>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my life :D

Answer (score 4):

Or:

```
<select id="select-test" resultMap="MyTableResult" parameterClass="list"> 
 select * from table where
 <iterate property="list" conjunction="OR">
  col1 = #list[]#
 </iterate>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select-test" parameterClass="list"resultMap="YourResultMap">
     select * from table where col_1 IN 
     <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
      #[]#
    </iterate>
</select>
```

Comment: Care to comment your code? If there is another accepted answer from 2 years ago with 9 upvotes, what does your answer adds that important that can be a usefull answer?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but for the users of MyBatis, the syntax is a bit different:

```
<select id="selectPostIn" resultType="domain.blog.Post">
  SELECT *
  FROM POST P
  WHERE ID in
  <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
      open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
  </foreach>
</select>
```

Refer to the [guide in here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this:

```
<select id="select-test" resultMap="MyTableResult" >
select * from my_table where col_1 in
 $listOfValues$
</select>
```

use the $ in the IN statement.

Comment: this generate something like [aaa,abb,acc] can you suggest how can i change this default `[]` into `()` because oracle doesn't support `[]`