# is it possible to pass an Array from java(ibatis) to postgresql function as parameter

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

i want pass bunch of Update queries in the form of array to `pl/pgsql` function as parameter and there i need to execute those `sql` update queries. is it possible.please help me to get out of this.

Comment: do you want someting like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637825/how-to-use-an-in-clause-in-ibatis

Comment: no sir not like that i want to pass array as argument to function.the array contains group of update queries and i want to execute those queries by iterating that array in that function

Comment: and that function also having other parameters

Comment: Have a look at this: [Passing Arrays as Arguments](http://joaopribs.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/passing-arrays-as-arguments-in-plpgsql-functions/). You can pass full statements in, iterate over the array, and execute them with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the array in is not to hard.  Generate a quoted csv list of the queries, surround by `{}` braces and pass that in as a bound parameter.  For example....

```
{"UPDATE foo SET bar = 1 where baz = 1","alter table foo add foobar int","drop database critical_prodiction_database"}
```

Then pass it in as a `text[]` parameter.